# Ruby on Rails, View properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I get this error and for the life of me I can't figure out why. Help would be appreciated. :

error 3: [error displayed after changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qnbbq.jpg)

error 4: [after User.all.each do |user|](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX1Kk.jpg)

Error: Undefined method 'each' for nil: nilClass

my ruby/haml code is as follows

viewer code:

```
-#  This file is app/views/projects/index.html.haml
%h1 All Project Tasks

= form_tag projects_path, :method => :get do
  Include: 
  - @all_users.each do |user|
    = user
    = check_box_tag "users[#{user}]", 1, ("checked" if @filtered_users.find_index(user))
  = submit_tag 'Refresh', :id => "users_submit"


%table#projects
  %thead
    %tr
      %th{:class => ("hilite" if params[:sort] == "title")}= link_to "Title", {:controller => "projects", :sort => "title", :filter => @filtered_users.to_s}, :id => "title_header"
      %th Task Details
      %th Assigned Usertimot
      %th{:class => ("hilite" if params[:sort] == "due_date")}= link_to "Due Date", {:controller => "projects", :sort => "due_date", :filter => @filtered_users.to_s}, :id => "due_date_header"
  %tbody
    - @projects.each do |project|
      %tr
        %td= project.title 
        %td= link_to "More about #{project.title}", project_path(project)
        %td= project.user
        %td= project.due_date.to_formatted_s(:long)
 = link_to 'Add new project task', new_project_path
```

controller code:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    id = params[:id] # retrieve project task ID from URI route
    @project = Project.find(id) # look up project task by unique ID
    # will render app/views/projects/show.<extension> by default

  def index
 @projects_users = Project.all_users  


# remembered settings
    if (params[:filter] == nil and params[:users] == nil and params[:sort] == nil and 
            (session[:filter] != nil or session[:users] != nil or session[:sort] != nil))
     if (params[:filter] == nil and session[:filter] != nil)
      params[:filter] = session[:filter]
     end
     if (params[:sort] == nil and session[:sort] != nil)
       params[:sort] = session[:sort]
      end
      redirect_to projects_path(:filter => params[:filter], :sort => params[:sort], :users => params[:users]) 
 else

      if (params[:filter] != nil and params[:filter] != "[]")
        @filtered_users = params[:filter].scan(/[\w-]+/)
       session[:filter] = params[:filter]
      else
       @filtered_users = params[:users] ? params[:users].keys : []
      session[:filter] = params[:users] ? params[:users].keys.to_s : nil
     end  
 end

 session[:sort] = params[:sort]
    session[:users] = params[:users] 


    if (params[:sort] == "title")
      if ( params[:users]or params[:filter] )
        @projects = Project.find(:all, :order => "title")
      end
 end
 if (params[:sort] == "due_date")
      if ( params[:users]or params[:filter] )
       @projects = Project.find(:all, :order => "due_date")
     end
    if (params[:sort] == nill)
    if(params[:users] or params[:filter])
     @projects = Project.all
    end
 end
end
end

 def new
  # default: render 'new' template
end

def create
    @project = Project.create!(project_params)
    flash[:notice] = "#{@project.title} was successfully created."
    redirect_to projects_path
 end

def edit
    @project = Project.find params[:id]
end

 def update
 @project = Project.find params[:id]
 @project.update_attributes!(project_params)
 flash[:notice] = "#{@project.title} was successfully updated."
 redirect_to project_path(@project)
end

 def destroy
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @project.destroy
  flash[:notice] = "Project '#{@project.title}' deleted."
  redirect_to projects_path
 end

  private
   def project_params
     params.require(:project).permit(:title, :description, :extended_description, :user, :due_date)
    end
end
end
```

i understand that the spacing for haml may be a little off, just the nature of trying to format the code block thanks in advance!

viewer code:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
def self.all_users
   allUsers = []
   Project.all.each do |project|
     if (allUsers.find_index(project.user) == nil)
       allUsers.push(project.user)
     end
    end
    return allUsers
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you please post the full exception backtrace as well as the controller action code for this view?

Comment: sure, give me a minute

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting the error on this line in your view:

```
@all_users.each do |user|
```

The reason for the error as I see it is that you don't have `@all_users` instantiated anywhere in your controller's `index` action method.

First switch `@all_users` to `@projects_users`.  Also it appears that your `all_users` method in `project.rb` is overly complex and is returning `nil`. Try modifying `project.rb` to the following:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.all_users
    all.includes(:user).map(&:user).uniq
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you please paste the full error from your Rails' console?

Comment: Thanks.  In your `app/models/project.rb` file, do you have a method or scope defined named `all_users`? I'm guessing that you do and that it is returning `nil`.  Could you share its contents?

Comment: I just changed AllUsers to all_users, not sure if this was a step in the right direction but its still erroring regardless

Comment: same error as before, shall i post another screenshot?

Comment: If you switch the line in your view from `@all_users.each do |user|` to `User.all.each do |user|` does that work?

Comment: it caught an exception. uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::User

Comment: Do you even have a `User` model and `users` table? What's the exception?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. It is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> Undefined method 'each' for nil: nilClass

This error basically means you **don't have any data in your variable**.

In other languages, it would mean you've not *delcared* the variable. Because Ruby is object orientated, it will populate the variable with the `nilClass` class.

Many new Ruby devs are thrown by the "undefined method" exception message; it's the `nilClass` you have to look out for.

--

To explain the error properly, because [Ruby is *object orientated*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), every *variable* is actually a *data object*, represented by a *class*. In Rails, you can define these classes as models (`User.find` etc).

Unlike other languages, Ruby treats these objects as is -- it uses *methods* on them. Other languages fit data into functions, E.G `PHP`'s `each` function:

```
#PHP
<$ each($people) $>

#Ruby
<% @people.each do |person| %>
```

Thus, the "no method" error basically means that Ruby cannot find the method you're calling on the `nilClass`. It throws developers because they think that *"I have the `x` method on the `User` class"*, not realizing that the variable has been populated by the `nilClass` instead.

The short of it is that you have to either make your calls conditional, or populate the variable properly.

---

The error appears to be here:

```
#app/views/project/index.html.haml
@all_users.each do |user|


#app/controllers/projects_controller.rb
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
   def index
       @projects_users = Project.all_users
   end
end
```

> 1. You're not assigning `@all_users` at all
> 2. You're using an inefficient way to get "all users"

Here's what I'd do:

```
#app/controllers/projects_controller.rb
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
   def index
       @users = Project.all_users
   end
end

#app/models/project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :all_users, -> { joins(:users) } #-> this needs to be tested
end

#app/views/projects/index.haml
- @users.each do |user|
  = user.name
```

I am pretty inexperienced with pure SQL, you'll be best referring to the [`joins` documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-a-single-association) for a clearer perspective.